# Rails access form parameter that is an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms

I have a form that allows for the entry of multiple ids like:

```
<input name="the_ids[]"  type="text" placeholder="Enter an ID" />
<input name="the_ids[]"  type="text" placeholder="Enter an ID" />
<input name="the_ids[]"  type="text" placeholder="Enter an ID" />
```

When the form submits I get the params being passed as:

```
"the_ids"=>["1, 2, 3"],
```

In the controller I am trying to access them as:

```
params[:the_ids[]].each do |id|
  do_something_with(id)
end
```

I keep getting the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
> params[:the_ids[]].each do |id|
```

The trace shows the following:

```
app/controllers/the_controller.rb:10:in `[]'
```

I cannot figure this out. I've reviewed some other posts and tried to access in alternative syntax like:

```
params["the_ids[]"]
```

But that produced an error stating that is was a nil class...

Please advise if more details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in `"the_ids"=>["1, 2, 3"]`, the parameter name is `the_ids` and you can access it using `params[:the_ids]`.

```
params[:the_ids].each do |id|
  do_something_with(id)
end
```

The use of `the_ids[]` in `name="the_ids[]"` is only needed on the client-side to tell Rails that `the_ids` is to be read as an array parameter.